# What target OSs does RedHawk Support

Tags: redhawksdr

I have not used RedHawk but am considering using it.  Reading the documentation it appears that RedHawk only supports development on varieties of Linux, but it is not clear whether this limitation also applies to target execution environment.  Can RedHawk support applications to run on non-Linux target hardware (cross-compile, CoreFramework, remote debug, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redhawk is not limited to running applications on Linux platforms, per the SCA standard. An ExecutableDevice (see http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/main.html, Section 6.4 'Executable Device') enables software to be copied to and run on a particular host, which does not have to be Linux-based. However, Redhawk does not provide any implementations, base class/helper libraries, development tools, etc. for other platforms, which makes this less practical.

The only exception to this is the SCA explorer, used to browse/interact with Redhawk domains (for Windows, available on SourceForge). Interacting with a running Redhawk domain from a different platform is fairly straight-forward using CORBA and the interfaces included with the Core Framework.